# Property does not exist on type when using custom type definition in typescript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express

I am trying to have custom properties(functions) in expressJS Response, but really cannot understand why I keep getting that `property does not exist on type`.

I have defined a custom definition file:

**index.d.ts**

```
/* eslint-disable no-unused-vars */

interface APIResponse {
  status?: number,
  message?: string | null,
  data?: any
}

declare global {
  namespace Express {
    interface Response {
      showDefaultErrorPage: (status: number) => Response<any, Record<string, any>, number>
      showErrorPage: (status: number) => Response<any, Record<string, any>, number>
      success: (options: APIResponse) => Response<any, Record<string, any>, number>
      error: (options: APIResponse) => Response<any, Record<string, any>, number>
    }
  }
}
```

**Express middleware**

```
const responseHelper = (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
  res.showDefaultErrorPage = (status: number = 500) => { // Error here
    // ...
  }

  res.showErrorPage = (status: number) => { // Error here
    // ...
  }

  res.success = (options = {}) => { // Error here
    const {
      status = 200,
      message = null,
      data
    } = options

    return res.status(status).json({
      status,
      message: message || getStatusMessage(status) || 'Success',
      data
    })
  }

  res.error = (options = {}) => { // Error here
    const {
      status = 500,
      message = null
    } = options

    return res.status(status).json({
      status,
      message: message || getStatusMessage(status) || 'Server error'
    })
  }

  next()
}

export default responseHelper
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
"target": "es2016", 
"module": "commonjs",
"rootDir": "./src",
"moduleResolution": "node",  
"typeRoots": [
    "./src/@types/express"
],
"outDir": "./build",
"esModuleInterop": true,
"forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
"strict": true,
"skipLibCheck": true
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding `index.d.ts` to the `files` entry in `tsconfig.json':

```
"files": [
 "index.d.ts"
]
```

You can also try `exporting` the `Response` interface. Something like this:

```
declare module 'express' {
    export interface Response {
      showDefaultErrorPage: (status: number) => Response<any, Record<string, any>, number>
      showErrorPage: (status: number) => Response<any, Record<string, any>, number>
      success: (options: APIResponse) => Response<any, Record<string, any>, number>
      error: (options: APIResponse) => Response<any, Record<string, any>, number>
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried doing the first option but it doesnt work. Doing the second option, throws errors in places like where I have used `express()`, `express.static(...)`